# problem with AJAXToolKit under ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

i am using the AjaxToolKit in my MVC Application as shown on
http://stephenwalther.com

AutoComplete & the Calender are working fine but i cant pass properties to the js part.
my generated javascript looks like this

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
Sys.Application.add_init(function(){
$create(AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarBehavior,{'Format':'MMMM d, yyyy','PopupButtonID':'Image1'},null,null,$get('Birthday'))});
</script>
```

but the calender still uses the default format, i know it has to be a minor error but i dont find it :(

tia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem myself, javascript is case sensitiv dohh :)